# Scraping div data technique using a regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, curl

I wish to scrape the div's data with div id from a remote server using curl. Actually this is problem of regex, I've content of the page in a variable for example:

```
$url = "http://www.google.co.in/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What is the proper syntax of regex to get the data data is in following format:

```
$content = "<div id="cat_list">
<h4>Browse by Category</h4>
<ul>
<li class="a"><a href="link1.php">category1</a></li>
<li class="b"><a href="link2.php">category2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>";
```

I need all the category names here.

Comment: Regexes are not very suited for parsing HTML, your best bet is probably something like PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser  ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex if you wanted to use it instead of a parser since its possibly faster and uses less overhead.

```
$content = <<<EOD
<div id="cat_list">
<h4>Browse by Category</h4>
<ul>
<li class="a"><a href="link1.php">category1</a></li>
<li class="b"><a href="link2.php">category2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
EOD;

$categories = array();

if (preg_match('/<div id="cat_list">(.*?)<\/div>/is', $content, $cat_list)) {
    $matches = preg_match_all('/<li[^>]*><a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>/i', $cat_list[1], $cats);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $matches; ++$i) {
        $categories[$cats[2][$i]] = array('href' => $cats[1][$i], 'name' => $cats[2][$i]);
    }
}

var_dump($categories);
```

Results:

```
array(2) {
  ["category1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["href"]=>
    string(9) "link1.php"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "category1"
  }
  ["category2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["href"]=>
    string(9) "link2.php"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "category2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for help that really works.. One another thing, if i've a div containing 4 ul, two from them have some class and other two doesn't have, so if  i want to select all li between those 4 ul then what should be done? i've tried it as

Comment: if (preg_match('/<div id="category-list">(.*?)<\/div>/is', $content, $cat_list)) {

Comment: $matches  = preg_match('/<ul[ class="ccl"]?>(.*?)<\/ul>/is', $cat_list[1], $content2);

Comment: }

sorry i need to write in a formated text thats's why i did in this manner.. it is showing me only first ul 's data thats it.. please tell me how i can have all li of those ul...

And thanks again for the help... :)